# VIRTUALENVWRAPPER fails with zlib import error after EL CAPITAN update

Tags: python, zlib, virtualenvwrapper

After a recent El Capitan update, when I open the terminal I get the error below without attempting anything.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 8, in <module>
        import inspect
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
        import tokenize
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 29, in <module>
        from itertools import chain
    ImportError: No module named itertools
    virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

    If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
    check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
    set properly.
```

If I run python (2.7.9) in the command line it works, but it fails when I try to import zlib with no module zlib error.

I tried to reinstall pip through easy install, so I can reinstall virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, but when I try sudo easy install I get "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available".

So I then tried to change the .bash_profile, but I really don't know how to change it, because I don't understand path and environmental variables. CURRENT bash_profile content is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

My last hope is that if I can point the path in the right direction everything will get solved.

Comment: Try using `brew` to reinstall Python. Somehow part of your current installation got borked.

Comment: thanks! won't this mess up my path variables and complicate things further?

Comment: Not at all. You're just reinstalling things that may have been damaged by the El Capitan update.

Comment: thanks again! I just tried brew install pythob but i got warning python 2.7.9 already installed. any suggestions?